# Copy content from a csv to PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, import

I am trying to copy content from a csv-file to an existing but empty table in PostgreSQL.
This is how far I've come:

```
COPY countries FROM 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\countries-20140629.csv'
DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER
```

The Problem that I'm experiencing is that the csv-file containts three columns (code, english_name and French_name), whereas my table only persists of two columns (code, english_name).
Adding a third column to my table is not an Option.

Is there any way to tell PostgreSQL to only import the first two columns of the csv-file?

Comment: Short answer: no. Possible workarounds: 1) edit the csv file, removing the second comma and everything that comes after it. 2) import into a temp table with the correct number of columns, and ignore the third column.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to modify your CSV and delete the last column.

You could try it like the documentation says:

In your case it would be like:

```
COPY countries (code, english_name) FROM 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\countries-20140629.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER
```

Take a look in the documentation for further help:
[PostgreSQL.org](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, there is no possibility to tell postgres to only import a subset of the columns. What you can do, is to import the csv file into a temporary table and then transfer the data you want from the temporary table to your final table.

Comment: It *is* possible, see motho's answer